# Making the PATH and other environment variables available in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, environment-variables

Working with emacs in OSX can some times be troubling.

I interchange with using the Terminal.app application and the emace *shell* both of these use bash, and both seem to work, I do however have the problem that the environment is not setup identically in both.

I'm running a clean installation of OSX Lion, and emacs 24 from [emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and would like for the environment variables in the emacs shell to make the same as in the Terminal.app under osx. How do I fix that?

Comment: Where are you setting these variables originally?

Comment: @isturdy: I've never actually set them my self, I'm using apple's setup from the terminal, and the defaults in emacs. what I would prefer would be emacs automatically making the emacs shell match the default system settings

Comment: To add missing paths, have you tried adding something like this to your .emacs file?:  (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin")) and (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/texbin")))  If that works for your situation, let me know and I'll create an answer -- I'm also using OSX and I use the above settings to run TexLive related stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just install the awesome little package [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) and you're done! It will automatically set your emacs `exec-path` to be same as the `PATH` in your `zsh/bash` config.

It will also allow you to copy the values of other shell variables like this:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "PYTHONPATH")
```

Comment: What about Windows? I have exec-path-from-shell preinstalled with spacemacs, but it fails to copy anything - cannot find internal or external command "printf"

Answer (score 3):

If your environment variables are being set in ~/.bash_profile, Create a file called ~/.emacs_bash and put in it the following:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Don't forget the newline at the end of that line or it won't be executed.

~/.emacs_bash is loaded by emacs when you run bash from within it, such as when using M-x shell or shell-command so you can use it to set any environment variables you want available.

Comment: If you were on Unix I would say use '. /etc/profile' but I'm not sure how the OSX Filesystem is mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Open Emacs.app from within Terminal.app (instead of from Finder):

```
$ emacs
```

This works for me using Emacs from Homebrew with Cocoa (`brew install emacs --with-cocoa`). It launches Emacs.app in a Cocoa GUI window (use `emacs -nw` to fallback to terminal UI). All the environment variables I have set in my bash environment appeared to be set in Emacs.

I have not tried this with Emacsformacosx. I personally prefer Emacs from Homebrew as I heard Emacsformacosx is not compiled with certain extensions I use such as TLS and Imagemagick... you can compile Emacs with those extensions using `brew install emacs --with-XXX`.

Comment: If you simply type emacs in Terminal, you may obtain an old version, without graphical support.   If you want to use the Mac OS X app, you can type something like /Applications/Emacs-25.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs (to be adapted to your installation) in Terminal, hence inherit exactly the calling shell parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, `exec-path-from-shell` will only pass `PATH` to Emacs, If you want to pass all environments, you can try:

- https://github.com/ersiner/osx-env-sync/