# Emacs not picking up environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs, environment-variables

I added my aws credentials to my environment variables in Mac OSX. I am trying to use datomic in emacs, but I'm getting an error that it can't get my AWS credentials. It seems like emacs is not picking up all of my environment variables. Why is this the case, and how can I set my environment variables so that emacs can access them? Thanks!

Comment: Add more detail ... have you exported the variables in the shell that you're starting emacs with?

Comment: How are you starting emacs?

Comment: I am starting emacs from the terminal in the /Users/myname directory by running ./emacs

Comment: The variables are in my .bash_profile file

Comment: When I try echo $PATH from the terminal I see my PATH variable, but when I try echo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID it  just prints AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Comment: @Syan31 `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`..? Only one is treated as a variable in sh.. as long as emacs is running as as subprocess of where the environment variables are defined, *and* the variables are set to export, emacs should have access per normal process inheritance.

Comment: I was going to mark this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16676826 (which may still be of interest to you), however you say you're starting Emacs from your shell, in which case it will inherit the shell's environment.  In Emacs you can check `C-h v initial-environment` and `C-h v process-environment`.

Comment: I ended up setting them in the shell right before starting emacs and it worked! Not sure why it wasn't picking it up from my environment variables file.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/reload-environment-variables