# Cannot locate Agda mode binary when running Emacs GUI on OSX

Tags: emacs, agda

Emacs (from https://emacsformacosx.com/) and Agda (via homebrew) both install gracefully. However when launching Emacs after running `agda-mode setup` I receive the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/user/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, /Users/user/zsh:1: command not found: agda-mode
```

Terminal version of Emacs loads Agda-mode properly and I tried [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) -library without success.

My .emacs has the following content:

```
(package-initialize)
(load-file
 (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
   (shell-command-to-string "agda-mode locate")))
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Does anyone have the same issue / knows how to fix it or where it comes from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the relevant part of your `.emacs` look like?

Comment: The full content is

 ```(package-initialize)

(load-file (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
                (shell-command-to-string "agda-mode locate")))

(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))```

Comment: Please excuse me for formatting. Couldn't find a way to enforce newlines.

Comment: NB, you can always edit your original question. I've added the config to it now.

Comment: I believe it's an issue about the GUI Emacs having a different copy of PATH where adga-mode is missing. Have you tried comparing what PATH looks like when you print it in the terminal and from GUI Emacs? You mention you tried _exec-path-from-shell_ and it didn't work. Does it change the value of PATH?

Comment: There are two related posts: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/emacs-and-command-line-path-disagreements-on-osx and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676826/making-the-path-and-other-environment-variables-available-in-emacs

Comment: Sounds like you should have installed a script or executable named `agda-mode` somewhere on your `PATH`, but failed to do so, or failed to update your `PATH` to include the location, perhaps because you are on `zsh`. Did the installation add anything to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.profile`? (All of these are optional; if they exist, they should be in your home directory.)

Comment: @tripleee OP mentioned that agda mode works when running Emacs from the terminal. So I believe it means it's on the PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on MacOS Catalina and GNU emacs. It turned out to be a path problem like @viam0Zah suggested. Here's what fixed it for me:

In the terminal, ran `echo $PATH` and compared to `agda-mode locate` to figure out what path is required to find agda-mode. For me, it was `/Users/aransil/.cabal/bin`.

In GNU emacs, used `(shell-command-to-string "echo $PATH")` to verify that the path variable is different and doesn't include `/Users/aransil/.cabal/bin`.

Back in the terminal, edited `~/.zshenv` by adding the line `export PATH=/Users/aransil/.cabal/bin:$PATH`

Restarted GNU emacs

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but in case someone else has the same issue. I believe everyone is on the right track that it is a path problem. On macos, things started from the GUI don't have the full shell path. This sexpr from your `.emacs` file should fix that:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

The issue is that the fix occurs after the `load-file` in your .emacs file. So the error occurs before the path is fixed. If you move that expression up to the top of the file, I think the problem will be fixed.